# mysql use between values in a join statement

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas, sqldf

I have the following two tables `dmu` and `ter`

```
>>> sqldf('select distinct begin, end from dmu', globals())
  begin end
0    56  65



>>> sqldf('select distinct begin, end from ter', globals())
   begin end
0      0   4
1      5   9
2      9  12
3     13  17
4     18  26
5     26  27
6     28  31
7     32  35
8     36  37
9     38  44
10    45  52
11    53  55
12    56  65
13    65  66
```

and I want to only select rows where `ter.begin` is between `dmu.begin - 15` and `dmu.begin`

i.e. the rows from `ter` will be:

```
10    45  52
11    53  55
12    56  65
13    65  66
```

So I have tried:

```
sqldf('select * from dmu 
       inner join ter 
       on ter.begin between dmu.begin - 15 and dmu.begin',
       globals())
```

(I am calling mysql from python but this shouldn't matter).

This returns an empty table! Why? Can I not use a between statement in the join statement? is the `- 15` part throwing it off somehow?

Comment: The sql statement does correctly return 3 rows when run directly in mysql.

Comment: Try putting parentheses around that math. `between (dmu.begin - 15) and`

Comment: Tried the parentheses with no luck. I'm convinced this is a pandas issue rather than mysql

Comment: I have discovered pandas uses sqlite and this is the issue. joins are declared slightly differently.